# SwiftUI List not showing images

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have created the following struct and here's a short example of my array that I wish to be used in a list in SwiftUI:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Rune: Identifiable {
    var runeName: String
    var runeImage: String
    var runeDescription: String
    let id = UUID()
}

let runesArray = [Rune(runeName: "Fehu", runeImage: String(("Fehu.png")), runeDescription: "(Description Goes Here"),
                  Rune(runeName: "Uruz", runeImage: String(("Uruz.png")), runeDescription: "(Description Goes Here"),
                  Rune(runeName: "Thurisaz", runeImage: String(("Thurisaz.png")), runeDescription: "(Description Goes Here"]
```

My images do not show up when I use the following code but my text runeName text runeDescription appears as expected when I click on the row and goto my DetailView and I can't figure out why:

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(runesArray) { rune in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(rune: rune)) {
                    RuneRow(rune: rune)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Rune Companion")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct RuneRow: View {
    
    let rune: Rune
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(rune.runeImage)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            Spacer()
            Text(rune.runeName)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

DetailView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    let rune: Rune
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(rune.runeImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                Spacer()
                Text(rune.runeDescription)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(rune.runeName)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
            
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView(rune: runesArray[0])
    }
}
```

When I change `Image(rune.runeImage)` to `Image("Fehu")` the image for Fehu does appear but populates all three rows as it should do, showing that my images can be loaded successfully. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify an extension (`.png`) for your images.

Replace:

```
runeImage: String(("Fehu.png"))
```

with:

```
runeImage: "Fehu"
```

when you create Runes in `runesArray`.

Comment: removing the extension .png has fixed this issue.